# JSON data not shown in DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

My application uses a list like this :

```
async Task<object> GetBanktAsync(string path)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    object result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>().Result;
    }
    var deserializeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<result>(resultString);
    dataGridViewBank.DataSource = deserializeObject;
}
```

Using the GET method to show banks from the DB in the DataGridview but it doesn't show anything. Why?

Comment: you need to RETURN something

Comment: Did you debug and see if the response contains data? Is the data correct when deserialized? Are you getting errors and if so: what error(s)?

Comment: can you please see here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159902/display-data-from-json-in-datagridview I asked with Detail Again